# Postgres groovy: trying to insert row only if it doesn't exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, groovy

I'm trying to insert a row into my table, only if it doesn't already exist (based on a unique id (myId)).  I don't want to query every single row before inserting as that takes some time.  I'd like to just try to insert, and if it fails that's fine.  Is there a way to do this?

At the moment, I'm doing:

```
    try {
        sqlObj.executeInsert(query)
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        println "Sql Exception"
    }
```

but this is kind of slow, as almost every row throws an exception in some cases.  Is there a way to handle this in SQL/Groovy/Postgresql?

Answer (score 1):

The [merge statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_%28SQL%29) in SQL lets you specify alternate logic for when a row exists or doesn't.  You could write something like:

```
MERGE INTO tablename USING table_reference ON (condition)
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT (column1 [, column2 ...]) VALUES (value1 [, value2 ...
```

(this is the wikipedia example with the "when matched" part removed.

It's a bit troubling that your select to check for the presence of the key takes a long time.  Are you using a select * statement rather than looping through all the rows in Java?  Also, is there an index on the id field?  If there isn't an index, the merge statement will have the same problem you are having now with respect to performance.

Comment: Unfortunately, postgres does not have a MERGE statement (yet). And it is not "troubling that is has to check for the existence of a key-value", the PK (or UNIQUE) constraint has to do this anyway.

Comment: What version of postgres doesn't have merge?  [Their wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SQL_MERGE) discusses it:

Comment: MERGE is still on the todo list: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-commands.html